# Проверка состояния

Tags: java, netty

У меня есть сервер и клиент.(Написанные на Java).
Они общаются между собой путем отправки пакетов.
Проблема заключается в том что если клиент выходит из программы то серверу отсылается пакет с данными. Проблема в том что если клиент внезапно выйдет(упадет отключится,цунами,потом,ураган) то серверу не отправится пакет об отключений клиента. И он будет считать что он подключен.
На netty как мне говорят создается канал по которому если обрывается связь то он умирает.Возможно ли это реализовать в Java?
Была идея отправлять каждую секунду от сервера клиенту пакет с данными "ping" и если ответ от клиента будет "pong" то продолжать с ним работу. Если ответа не будет то удалять его из сервера как работающего.

Что вы мне посоветует?
Я плохо конечно разбираюсь в сокетах(пока что)
Но там можно от сервера принимать подключения а клиент может подлючаться и получать информацию.
Только я  в этом не понял что будет если закрыть соеденение.
Будет ли сообщение клиенту и серверу о разрыве соеденения?

Comment: Если у вас сервер с клиентом держут соединение по TCP, то в настройках соединения сервера можно установить timeout, после которого бросается **java.net.SocketException**, означающий, что соединение с клиентом завершилось внезапно. Достататочно его перехватить.

Answer (score 3):

В "[Netty in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/netty-in-action)" есть глава посвящённая этой теме. Код оттуда как раз решает вашу задачу:

```
public class IdleStateHandlerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        pipeline.addLast(new HeartbeatHandler());
    }

    public static final class HeartbeatHandler extends ChannelStateHandlerAdapter {
        private static final ByteBuf HEARTBEAT_SEQUENCE =
            Unpooled.unreleasableBuffer(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("HEARTBEAT",
                CharsetUtil.ISO_8859_1));

        @Override
        public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
            if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
                ctx.writeAndFlush(HEARTBEAT_SEQUENCE.duplicate())
                    .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE_ON_FAILURE);
            } else {
                super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```